# New to Salesforce - Need a simple Apex trigger to update field based on Select from another custom object

Tags: apex, trigger

Apologies in advance, I have looked at examples and while I understand what I want to do and could do it in SQL, etc. Salesforce is new to me and finding the correct syntax is causing me problems.

So i have a custom object **QTR_Mapping__c**, this has two text fields **QTR__C**, **Year__c** and checkbox **isActive__C**.

Only one record in the custom object has `isActive__c = True`.

I have a second custom object **DD_Detail__c**, which has a text field **CurrentQTR__c**.

On creating a new record in **DD_Detail__c**,  I want the trigger to populate **CurrentQTR__c** to the value of **QTR__C** from **QTR_Mapping__c** where `isActive__c = True`

Thank you in advance for any help offered.

The examples I have viewed have been focused on mapping a field value in one object to a lookup table to identify associated value and using that to update etc.

I believe what I need to do is create a trigger, create a string, load the value of **QTR__c** from **QTR_Mapping__c** where *`isActive`* is true to the string, update the **CurrentQTR** to the string value.

Comment: Hi Ian, Welcome to SFSE. Your approach is on the right track, have you tried anything so far on writing a trigger? You may like to explore a bit on that and attempt to write a trigger, that way you will learn something new as well. Once you are there, and if you still have issues, you can edit your question, so that anyone can help you here. In this forum, we try to keep problems very specific. Because even if someone may write one for your, you will be only able to make most of it, if you know the syntax of triggers, SOQL, etc. You should visit trailhead for resources on writing trigger.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! We'll be able to provide you more targeted advice if you [edit] your question to include the code that you've tried to write so far, and any errors (verbatim) that you're running into. If you haven't already been through trailhead, https://trailhead.salesforce.com is a good (and official) resource for learning the basics of the Salesforce platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the gist of what you want to do. For production code I'd recommend organizing the code better into classes and methods instead of dumping everything into the trigger body.

```
trigger DdDetailLookupQtrTrigger on DD_Detail__c (before insert) {

    // Retrieve the active QTR_Mapping__c record,
    // assuming naively that only one is ever active
    QTR_Mapping__c activeMapping = [
        SELECT Id, QTR__c, Year__c
        FROM QTR_Mapping__c
        WHERE IsActive__c = TRUE
    ];

    // Update all DD_Detail__c records being created to hold the QTR__c
    // value from the active QTR_Mapping__c record
    for (DD_Detail__c eachRecord : Trigger.new) {
        eachRecord.CurrentQTR__c = activeMapping.QTR__c;
    }
}
```

On a separate note there are likely different ways you could achieve the same functional outcome without code. For example, you could use infer the quarter based on the current date, or simply hold the current quarter text in a [hierarchy-type custom setting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cs_accessing.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I had the correct trigger and SOQL, It was the last bit I was missing.  I couldn't use real dates as the Q3 entry is actually made in Q4. And it is a field that the user shouldnt be able to change. Originally I went with a global value, but this has to change each QTR and in production for my org we have no access to admin setup